# Vagrant. How can I change owner and group of hfs synced folders?

Tags: nginx, webserver, file-permissions, vagrant, hfs

sorry for my poor English knowledge.

I use vagrant. Recently I've enabled hfs feature for my synced folder (/srv/www). I've found out that group and owner of synced folder and files within are synced as well. So I try to change owner and group of my files to www-data:www-data for all files.

How can I made it? If it is impossible how can I customize default user:group of vagrant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible and not necessary, choose the different way to solve the problem.